# F# SqlProvider finding no tables in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, f#

With the code below, the `ctx` finds no tables.  The provider appears to be making a connection to the database, but only the functions:

- ClearUpdates
- CreationConnection
- GetUpdates
- SubmitUpdates

Show up in intellisense.  I have confirmed that the exact same connection string works, and allows querying of the tables when using NpgSql directly. I am using the latest stable version of NpgSql, PostgreSQL, and the latest preprelease of  SqlProvider, under Visual Studio 2015, F# 4.0

```
open FSharp.Data.Sql

let [<Literal>] connectionString = @"Server=127.0.0.1;Pooling=false;User Id=suave; Password=1234;Database=AlphamantisTiming;"
let [<Literal>] npgPath = @"C:\projects\AlphaFront\packages\Npgsql.3.0.5\lib\net45"
type sql = SqlDataProvider<
            ConnectionString = connectionString,
            DatabaseVendor = Common.DatabaseProviderTypes.POSTGRESQL,
            ResolutionPath = npgPath,
            IndividualsAmount = 1000,
            UseOptionTypes = true>


let ctx = sql.GetDataContext()
ctx. //no tables show up in intellisense
```

Comment: Just FYI - there can be issues with using Npgsql of version 3.x, e.g. https://github.com/fsprojects/SQLProvider/issues/188, https://github.com/fsprojects/SQLProvider/issues/154 I prefer use old 2.x version to avoid it.

Comment: Yeah I think for my purposes I will just have to wait until SQLProvider is more mature.  I hope it gets there, it is a neat idea.

Answer (score 2):

I found that the problem was insufficient permissions for the user.  More than the default permissions are required. Setting the user to be a superuser will work, but I assume there are safer options than that as well. Consult a DBA near you.